# access a component on one of tabsheets from datamodule

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, datamodule

Maybe trivial,but can't seem to figure it out....
I am using RAIZE components i.e  rzPageControl1 and one of my sheets is called
PRO.It (rzPageControl1) resides on Form1.
Now,I have an cxTextEdit4 on that sheet which I need to access from 
Datamodule2.Tablename2 on new record event.

But cant seem to access it properly...

Does anyone know the syntax ?

I tried ;
Form1.rzPageControl1.  etc but cant seem to make delphi list me the components
available....
Please help ...

Comment: You added the unit to the uses clause before you tried to access things inside Unit2 from inside Unit3 right? You didn't list your unit names, so it's pretty hard to help you. Seems like maybe you don't understand Uses-clauses yet?

Comment: Yes,I added Unit1 to uses clause (and viceversa).

Comment: I did not change unit names since I only have 2 (unit1 is form1 and unit2 is datamodule2)

Comment: In addition to the answers to your actual problem, I would like to point out that maybe accessing the user interface from your datamodule is potentially a sub-optimal design in terms of being able to re-use your datamodule (and hence business logic). Better to create your own datamodule-level events, and hook up the event handlers in the form.  E.g. in FormCreate - MyDataModule.OnNewCustomerRecord := HandleNewCustomerRecord. Where the "HandleNewCustomerRecord" is a method of your form.

Comment: Stuart: Good point.   Either separate your data module from your UI, or don't but don't make a big ball of mud, cher monsieur user.

Comment: +1 for stuart. Let me make that even stronger: DO NOT DIRECTLY REFER TO COMPONENTS ON A FORM, FRAME OR DATA MODULE FROM OUTSIDE THAT FORM/FRAME/DATAMODULE. The proper way is to go indirect: introduce one or more property/method on the target Form/Frame/DataModule that translates into accessing the right component. Always go the indirect way, because that reduces the number of dependencies you have between different modules, and lessens the maintenance burden that you already have. It for instance makes it way easier to replace a TLabel with a TStaticText.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The components on the form are all in the top level scope under the name of the form itself, and are not sub-component properties of your page control.

You want Form1.Button1, not Form1.rzPageControl1.Button1, even if Button1 is physically dropped onto rzPageControl1.

In delphi terms we say that the Button is `OWNED` by the Form, but it is `PARENTED` by a tab  on the page control, meaning it appears as part of the particular sub-page on the page control, but it still belongs (is owned) from memory point of view, and a scope point of view, by the form.

Comment: that was the first thing I did but delphi was marking my code as erroneus as I was typing... So I tought I must call specific sheet ... I will try once more later.... Guess I am too tired now...

Comment: It seems I missed a piece of vital info while I was typing (that's what you get when you stay awake all night) and thats why the compiler was giving me the error. however Warren,you are right...Form is the owner of everything.This put me on the right track so I was able to find the error too...Thank you all... About the datamodule : Personally,I do not like to use it.If I have many forms I prefer to have all tables/queries on respected forms.But if you use pagecontrol and pages then its nearly a must.Thank you all ...

Comment: You could consider putting all your content for your pages on separate frames (or if you hate frames, then forms), and wait to instantiate them until at runtime. This would reduce size and complexity of your MegaForm, and in the future if some of the pages become dynamic, or optional, you would already be set up for that case.  MegaForms, especially tabbed notebooks full of GUI controls tend to become unmaintainable messes, even if you do use data modules.